# Moving git repos to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have git server running over ssh.  All git repos are under /opt/git/repos folder on my git server.

Now on the same server I installed gitlab.  The url to the server remains the same.  The folder where gitlab looks for repos is /opt/gitlab.

My question is, how do I move / import my existing repos under /opt/git/repos into /opt/gitlab so that gitlab can see them?

I am doing this on centos 6.x

Comment: I don't think there is a import-functionality, the cleanest way would be creating the repo's in the panel and pushing them to gitlab.

Comment: You can add another origin - and push your local repo to it.

Comment: I am new to git.  Some more technical hint will be very helpful.  Thanks in advance..

Comment: I suspect the answer is (a) create the corresponding repository using the gitlab web UI, (b) configure ssh credentials if you're using ssh as your git transport, (c) `git push` your repositories to gitlab.  Posted as a comment and not an answer because I don't have a gitlab instance to play with right now.

Comment: That helped.  Giving you the detailed steps as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performed below steps:

1. Crate a project for the git repo to be imported using gitlab gui.
2. Executed below commands on the local system where I have the git repos cloned.

> $ git remote add gitlab http://git.xxx.com/username/my-git-repo.git#
>
> $ git push gitlab --mirror

Please note that I have copied the http address of the git repo from the gui after creating it.